# How to show all the rows in my faq page from my faq table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a FAQ page. The page is only able show the last row of question with respect to its answer in the database. I want it to collapse and show the answer with respect to its question when I clicked all questions I have in the database. How should I go about doing it? Thanks! Appreciated lots!
panel. I want it to be shown as:

Question A

- Answer A

Question B

- Answer B

Question C

- Answer C

Now it is showing only this:

Question C

- Answer C

Table Structure:

**#       Name    Type Collation Null Default**
1   Id  Int         No  None
2   Question Varchar    Latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
3   Answer  Varchar Latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
4   Status  Varchar Latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
5   Date_added  Date            No  None

Below is my code:

```
 <h1>FAQ</h1>
    <?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY id ASC;");
     if($result >= 1 ){             

        $i=1;



  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {  $id = $row["id"];  

?> 
 <?php

      $i++;  }

    }
?>

   <?php       
   $queryquestion = mysql_query("SELECT question FROM faq where status='Enabled' AND id='$id' ORDER BY id ASC;")or die(mysql_error());
   $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryquestion); 
   $question = $data['question'];
   $rows = mysql_num_rows($queryquestion);   

  if($rows != 0){             
        echo '
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        ';   

  $i = 0; $j = 0;
  while($i < $rows)

        {   
       $queryanswer = mysql_query("SELECT answer FROM faq WHERE id='$id' AND question='$question'") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryanswer);
        $answer = $data['answer'];   
              echo
              '
         <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$i.'">
    '.$question.'</h4>
        </a></div>

       <div id="collapse'.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">

      <div class="panel-body">'.$answer.'</div>

         </div>
        </div>
        ';
        $i++;
 }
      echo'     
           </div>
         ';
    }else{
        echo "No Questions Found";
    }

?>
```

Comment: blah, blah, blah mysql_ deprecated.

Comment: Are your questions and answers stored in different tables?

Comment: Please provide table structures.

Comment: I cannot understand the purpose of those queries and loops.

Comment: Neither can I. You're selecting the same stuff twice. What's the point of that?

Comment: what do u actully want??

Comment: @JimmyT. The first query is to loop the all the ID from faq table. Whereas the second loop is to retrieve out the question and answer from where the id='$id'(the id that I have looped in the first loop.)

Comment: @cen No. They are stored in the same table

Comment: @Drudge I have modify the quesetion. Do take a look above. Thanks!

Comment: @user2946964 I know. I asked you to provide the table structure. EXPLAIN tablename; or CREATE statement.

Comment: you had written $answer in query where is that variable?

Comment: @Drudge Sry. I have made minor changes to the question. Do look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: @cen I have include my table structure in the question. Do take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @AdRock Nope. They are stored in the same table.

Comment: @user2946964 But why do you need a second query when you get the results in the first?

Answer (score 1):

It is too much brother.. ok then you should write the code below.Now it should work bro .. :-)

```
<h1>FAQ</h1>
    <?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY id ASC;");
     if($result >= 1 ){             

        $i=1;



  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {  $id = $row["id"];  
        //echo $id;

?> 
 <?php

      $i++;  }

    }
?>

   <?php       
   $queryquestion = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq where status='Enabled'  ORDER BY id ASC;")or die(mysql_error());



   $rows = mysql_num_rows($queryquestion);   

  if($rows != 0){             
        echo '
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        ';   

  $i = 0; $j = 0;
  while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryquestion))
  {



              echo
              '
         <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$i.'">
    '.$data['question'].'</h4>
        </a></div>

       <div id="collapse'.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">

      <div class="panel-body">'.$data['answer'].'</div>

         </div>
        </div>
        ';
        $i++;
 }
      echo'     
           </div>
         ';
    }else{
        echo "No Questions Found";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time to help me. However, when i tried to use your edited code on my page, it couldn't get the result that I want. It shows this: Question A, Answer A and keep repeating these first two information.

Comment: I can't seem to place your code inside my design. It does not work out. =(

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop using mysql_ functions. They are deprecated and unsafe. Learn to use PDO instead. Here is a nice reference: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html
2. You are doing the queries all wrong. There is no need to first select question from the table and then loop over those questions for answers.. just SELECT * or SELECT `question`, `answer` ... You can select multiple columns at once not just one.

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `faq` WHERE `Status`='Enabled' ORDER BY id");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll();

$i=0;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $i++;
    echo "<h2>Question $i</h2>";
    echo "<p>".$row['Question']."</p>";
    echo "Answer: ".$row['Answer'];
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @cen! I will take a look at the link that you gave. But I feel that there are problems with my queries that disallow me to get my result. I will try to debug. If not, I will try to use PDO. Thanks for your help!